Siunitx: spread table content accross page
I create a table where numbers are included, and since the numbers were not aligned properly with each other vertically, I decided to the sunitx package to tidy up the numbers. This is the code I used:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,caption,subcaption,array,threeparttable,float}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2,
    table-format=2.2,
    group-separator={,},
}        

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *{4}{S[table-format=-2.2]}}
            \toprule
            Test & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ADF test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PP test} \\ 
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
            Variables  & {Level} & {First difference} & {Level} & {First difference} \\ 
            \midrule
            $\log$CO\textsubscript{2} & -0.13 & -4.91\textsuperscript{***}  & -0.85 & -16.20\textsuperscript{***} \\ 
            $\log$GDP  & -3.69 & -7.09\textsuperscript{***} & -4.59 & -14.27\textsuperscript{***} \\
            $\log$FD & -2.01 & -5.78\textsuperscript{***}  & -4.01\textsuperscript{**} & -5.77\textsuperscript{***} \\
            $\log$EC  & -1.47\textsuperscript{***} & -5.73\textsuperscript{***} & -1.53\textsuperscript{***} & -5.74\textsuperscript{***} \\
            $\log$TO & -0.40 & -3.67\textsuperscript{***} & -0.16\textsuperscript{**} & -0.29\textsuperscript{***} \\
            $\log$URB & -0.23 & -3.68\textsuperscript{***}  & -0.28\textsuperscript{**} & -3.35\textsuperscript{***} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
            \item Note: ** and *** indicate significance levels at 5\% and 1\% respectively.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{Tab:unit_root_tests}
\end{table}

\end{document}

However, running the code gives me the following output:

As you can see, there is too much empty space at the right of the table. How can I fix this and spread the table content across the table?

never use \begin{tabularx} if here are no X use tabular* (or just centre the table and don't make it harder to read by spreading it out)

@DavidCarlisle removing \begin{tabularx} doesn't fix the problem.

Yes, it does, you need to use tabular* if you want to stretch it (as egreg has shown)  or (better) don't stretch it and just use \centering to center it.

Use tabular* instead.
I made other changes, as you don't need threeparttable for this application. Also \textsuperscript{***} is not only a mouthful, but the output is really awful.
Note also the column specifier including \st{***} so the relative space is taken into account.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2,
    group-separator={,},
}

\newcommand{\st}[1]{$^{#1}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\caption{Unit root tests}
\label{Tab:unit_root_tests}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{4}{S[table-format=-2.2\st{***}]}
}
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test \\Variables \end{tabular}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ADF test} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{PP test} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
& {Level} & {First difference} & {Level} & {First difference} \\ 
\midrule
$\log\mathrm{CO}_2$ & -0.13 & -4.91\st{***}  & -0.85 & -16.20\st{***} \\ 
$\log\mathrm{GDP}$  & -3.69 & -7.09\st{***} & -4.59 & -14.27\st{***} \\
$\log\mathrm{FD}$   & -2.01 & -5.78\st{***}  & -4.01\st{**} & -5.77\st{***} \\
$\log\mathrm{EC}$   & -1.47\st{***} & -5.73\st{***} & -1.53\st{***} & -5.74\st{***} \\
$\log\mathrm{TO}$   & -0.40 & -3.67\st{***} & -0.16\st{**} & -0.29\st{***} \\
$\log\mathrm{URB}$  & -0.23 & -3.68\st{***}  & -0.28\st{**} & -3.35\st{***} \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize
  Note: \st{**} and \st{***} indicate significance levels at 5\% and 1\% respectively.}
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}


Look at how I produced the header of the first column and also the \log parts.

Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.

Just for the sake of comparison, here are (a) a solution that uses tabularx (properly), with five equally wide columns, and (b) a solution that uses a basic tabular environment. Speaking for myself, the tabular-based solution would appear to be preferable to the tabularx and tabular* solutions.
Aside: There's no need to load the array and caption packages explicitly, as they get loaded automatically by the tabularx and subcaption packages, respectively.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,siunitx,subcaption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand{\st}[1]{$^{#1}$}
\newcommand{\mC}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathrm{#1}} % for typesetting variable names
\sisetup{
    %round-mode=places, 
    %round-precision=2,
    group-separator={,}
}        

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

%\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Unit root tests}\label{Tab:unit_root_tests}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
   X 
   *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2\st{***}]} 
   S[table-format=-2.2\st{***}]
   @{}}
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Test} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ADF test} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{PP test} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
  & \mC{Level} & \mC{First difference} & \mC{Level} & \mC{First difference} \\ 
\midrule
$\log\vn{CO_2}$ & -0.13         & -4.91\st{***} & -0.85         & -16.20\st{***} \\ 
$\log\vn{GDP}$  & -3.69         & -7.09\st{***} & -4.59         & -14.27\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{FD}$   & -2.01         & -5.78\st{***} & -4.01\st{**}  &  -5.77\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{EC}$   & -1.47\st{***} & -5.73\st{***} & -1.53\st{***} &  -5.74\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{TO}$   & -0.40         & -3.67\st{***} & -0.16\st{**}  &  -0.29\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{URB}$  & -0.23         & -3.68\st{***} & -0.28\st{**}  &  -3.35\st{***} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Note: ** and *** indicate significance at the 5\% and 1\% levels, respectively.}\\
\end{tabularx}
%\end{threepartttable}

\vspace{1cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} 
   l 
   *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2\st{***}]} 
   S[table-format=-2.2\st{***}]
   @{}}
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Test} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ADF test} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{PP test} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
  & {Level} & {First difference} & {Level} & {First difference} \\ 
\midrule
$\log\vn{CO_2}$ & -0.13         & -4.91\st{***} & -0.85         & -16.20\st{***} \\ 
$\log\vn{GDP}$  & -3.69         & -7.09\st{***} & -4.59         & -14.27\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{FD}$   & -2.01         & -5.78\st{***} & -4.01\st{**}  &  -5.77\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{EC}$   & -1.47\st{***} & -5.73\st{***} & -1.53\st{***} &  -5.74\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{TO}$   & -0.40         & -3.67\st{***} & -0.16\st{**}  &  -0.29\st{***} \\
$\log\vn{URB}$  & -0.23         & -3.68\st{***} & -0.28\st{**}  &  -3.35\st{***} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Note: ** and *** indicate significance at the 5\% and 1\% levels, respectively.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you for the alternative solution.
